# HDD Desktop and Laptop Conversion

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, conversion, desktop

So I currently purchased a desktop. It's arriving in 10-15 days so this gives me time to think about anything I'd like to add on to it. I have this laptop that dates back to October of 2008 and I was wondering whether or not I could use the HDD in the laptop, for my desktop.

Desktop HDD Specs: 1TB SATA-III 6.0Gb/s 32MB Cache 7200RPM HDD

Laptop HDD Specs: 160GB ATA (And Discontinued Specs.)

Can I use the Laptop HDD in the Desktop? Something to note is that my laptop HDD runs on Windows Vista, and my desktop runs on Windows 8.1

Comment: Does the laptop HD have a SATA connector, that can plug into your desktop data & power connectors? If yes, then you can use it. If it's got a funny different connector (PATA or other), then could do as Hennes advises. It's not clear from your question what type the old HD is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer:
Check if your new bought desktops has a PATA connector on its motherboard? If not you are out of luck.

Long answer:

- In ye ages of lore, desktops PCs used something which was sometimes called IDE and sometimes called ATA. This used a 40 pins connector plus power.
- In those same forgotten ages laptops used a similar version but with 44 pins (which carried both the 40 signals from the desktop plus the power).
- These days both use SATA and have the same connector.

The SATA connector is completely different from any of the old PATA connectors. These are not going to work.  To access the old laptop drive either:

- Get an old external laptop enclosure. Put the old drive in that. Then connects its plug (e.g. firewire or USB) to the modern desktop.
- Or get a PCI[e] PATA controller and a 40 pins ATA to 44 pins ATA convertor.
- Or use a truly old motherboard.

But just out-of-the-box with an old 44 pins PATA drive and a modern motherboard: Forget it.

Comment: Upvote for using "ye ages of lore" in an answer :)